# Derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation

Question: Find the derivative of

$$
f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\Large\frac{1}{x}}
$$

Tip: convert $f(x)$ to $e^{g(x)}$.

How does one convert $f(x)$ to $e^{g(x)}$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $$y = z^a \implies \ln y = \ln (z^a) = a \ln z \implies y = e^{a \ln z}$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiation of $x^{\sqrt{x}}$, how?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/differentiation-of-x-sqrtx-how)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the simple example $y = a^x$ where $a$ is a number. We have:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
y &=& a^x \, , \\
\ln y &=& x\ln a \, , \\
e^{\ln y} &=& e^{x\ln a} \, , \\
y &=& e^{x\ln a} \, . 
\end{array}$$

Thus, in your case $(1/x)^{1/x} \equiv e^{(1/x)\ln(1/x)} \equiv e^{-(\ln x)/x}.$ Now use the chain rule to to differentiate.

Comment: Why do you use $\equiv$ instead of $=$?

Comment: @xavierm02 The symbol $\equiv$ is used for an identity, i.e. an equation that holds for all values. For example $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta \equiv 1$. That's because the left-hand side and right-hand side are equal *for all values* of $\theta$. On the other hand, $\sin\theta = 0$ only holds *for some values* of $\theta$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$f(x)=e^{(1/x)\cdot\ln(1/x)}.$$
In your case, we can think of this as using the chain rule with $g(x)=e^{x\ln(x)}$ and $h(x)=1/x$ so that $f(x)=g\circ h(x)$. The chain rule implies that $f'(x)=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)$, thus 
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln(\frac{1}{x})\right)'e^{(1/x)\ln(1/x)}\\ \\ &=\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(1/x)-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)e^{(1/x)\ln(1/x)}\\ \\ &=\left(-\frac{\ln(1/x)+1}{x^2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/x}
\end{align}

Comment: I am a little slow to follow but should it not be $h(x)=1/x\ln(x)$ and $g(x)=e^x$? second or third line?

Comment: @Freddy: If $h(x)=-(1/x)\ln(x)$ instead, then what you have works just fine. The problem is that we need two $x^{-1}$ and your equation only gives one.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways come to mind without the rewrite... sorry I have answered the  title rather than the actual question.

Let $y(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$. Now take the natural logarithm of both sides:

$\ln(y(x))=\ln\left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right)=g(x)\ln(f(x))$.

This may only be done where $f(x)>0$ but for $y$ to be defined in the first place we need this anyway. Now differentiate both sides implicitly with respect to $x$ using power rule:

$\frac{1}{y(x)}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x)\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)+g'(x)\cdot\ln(f(x))$.

Now multiply across by $y(x)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x)\cdot f(x)^{g(x)-1}\cdot f'(x)+f(x)^{g(x)}\cdot \ln(f(x))\cdot g'(x)$.

**Alternate Solution**

Let $y(f,g)=f^g$ where $f=f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Now use this Chain Rule

$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t),y(t))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$

Thus we have

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(gf^{g-1})\cdot \frac{df}{dx}+(f^g\ln(f))\cdot \frac{dg}{dx}$

which is of course the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $g(x)=\log f(x)$ then $f'(x) = g'(x) f(x)$.  So you really only need to compute the derivative of $g(x)=\log (1/x)^{1/x} = \frac{-\log x}{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

First, recall that for $\;h(x) = e^x, h^{-1}(x) = \ln x,\;$ so $\;h(h^{-1}(x)) = x$. 
So, in this case, $\;f(x) = e^{\large\ln(f(x))}$

Then, to answer your question, with your function in hand: 
$$
 \begin{align} 
f(x) &=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/x} \\ \\ 
&=e^{\ln\left((1/x)^{\large 1/x}\right)} \\ \\
&= e^{\large(1/x)\cdot\ln(1/x)} \\ \\
&= e^{\large-\large(\ln x)/x}
\end{align}
$$
Now use the chain-rule to derivate.