# Differentiating $f(x)^{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there any general rule for what the derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ (where $f(x),g(x)$ are differentiable functions) is in terms of $f(x),g(x),f'(x),g'(x)$.

In other words is there something analogous to product,chain and quotient rules for such expressions?

Comment: Related: [Differentiation of $x^{\sqrt x}$, how?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/differentiation-of-x-sqrtx-how)

Comment: Very related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276041/derivative-of-fxgx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is, note that
$$
f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g(x)\log f(x)}
$$
so differentiating gives
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(\cdot) =f(x)^{g(x)}\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)\log f(x)) = f(x)^{g(x)}(g'(x)\log f(x) + g(x) \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)})
$$
Make sure to be careful about this derivative existing though.

Answer (score 3):

Where this makes sense (that is, where the derivative exists), we can use the chain rule and product rule on $$f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\cdot\ln(f(x))}$$

Answer (score 1):

What about logarithmic differentiation?
$$h=f^g\Rightarrow \ln h=g\cdot \ln f\Rightarrow \frac{h'}{h}=g'\cdot\ln f+\frac{f'}{f}\Rightarrow h'=h\bigl(g'\cdot\ln f+\frac{f'}{f}\bigr)$$