# Derivative of $(\ln x)^{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, function-and-relation-composition

How can I differentiate the following function? $$f(x)=(\ln x)^{\ln x}.$$ Is it a composition of functions? And if so, which functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Derivative of $g(x)^{h(x)}=e^{h(x)\ln{g(x)}}$ is $e^{h(x)\ln{g(x)}}(h(x)\ln{g(x)})'$ and so on...

Comment: The derivative of $\ln f(x)$ is $f'(x)/f(x)$.

Comment: Or, set $u(x)=v(x)=\ln x$, and $g(u,v)=u^v$. Then $${d\over dx} g(u,v)={\partial g\over \partial u} {du\over dx}+{\partial g\over\partial v}{dv\over dx}.$$

Comment: To answer your first question, this is not a composition of functions; rather, $ \ f(x) \ $ can be considered a sort of "generalized exponential function".  A successful approach for finding its derivative is logarithmic differentiation, which is the method the other commenters are referring to.

Comment: Substitute $y=\ln x$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiation of $x^{\sqrt{x}}$, how?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/differentiation-of-x-sqrtx-how)

Comment: @MJD Should I do something in order to delete the duplicate?

Comment: @Charlie Nope, no need. You did nothing wrong. But you might be interested to visit the page at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/differentiation-of-x-sqrtx-how?lq=1 , read the answers there, and maybe read the answers on the pages listed under "linked" in the right-hand sidebar, because they're all answers to your question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$a^b = {\left(e^{\ln a}\right)}^b = e^{b\ln a}$$

so $$\left(\ln x\right)^{\ln x} = {\left(e^{\ln\ln x}\right)}^{\ln x}\\
= e^{\ln x\cdot\ln\ln x} = x^{\ln \ln x}$$ either of which which you should be able to do with methods you already know.

We can apply this technique generally to calculate the derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$:

$$f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g\ln f}$$

so $$\begin{align}
\frac d{dx} f^g  = \frac d{dx} e^{g\cdot\ln f} & = \left(\frac d{dx} \left(g\cdot\ln f\right)\right)e^{g\cdot\ln f}\qquad\text{(chain rule)}\\& = \left(\frac d{dx} \left(g\cdot\ln f\right)\right)f^g \\
& = \left(g'\ln f + \frac {gf'}f\right)f^g\qquad\text{(product rule)}
\end{align} $$

where $f' =\frac{df}{dx}$ and $g' = \frac{dg}{dx}$.

Answer (score 7):

The function $f$ can be expressed as
$$
f(x)=(\ln x)^{\ln x}=\mathrm{e}^{(\ln x)\ln(\ln x)}.
$$
Hence $f(x)=\exp\big(g(x)\big)$, where $g(x)=(\ln x)\ln(\ln x)$, and thus
$$
f'(x)=\left(\mathrm{e}^{(\ln x)\ln(\ln x)}\right)'=\mathrm{e}^{(\ln x)\ln(\ln x)}
\left((\ln x)\ln(\ln x)\right)'=(\ln x)^{\ln x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln(\ln x)+\ln x\frac{1}{x\ln x}\right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

We define $f(x):= x^x \Rightarrow (f\circ\ln)(x)=\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}$
And by the chain rule $f'(x)=(x^x)'=(e^{x\ln(x)})'= (x\ln(x))'e^{x\ln(x)}=e^{x\ln(x)}(\ln(x)+1)= (\ln(x)+1)x^x$

Now also by the chain rule $(f\circ\ln)'(x) = f'(\ln(x))\cdot(\ln(x))'=((\ln(\ln(x))+1)\ln(x)^{\ln(x)})\cdot \frac{1}{x} = \frac{(\ln(\ln(x))+1)\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}}{x}$