# Derivative of $n^{\log n}$?

Tags: calculus, algorithms, asymptotics

What would be the derivative of $n^{\log n}$? I have to prove that $(\log n)^n$ = $\omega$($n^{\log n}$). I am trying to implement L'Hopital rule.

Comment: You could use $[\log f(x)]'=f'(x)/f(x)$. Apply it to $f(x)=x^{\log x}$; note $\log f(x)=\log x\cdot\log x$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiation of $x^{\sqrt{x}}$, how?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/differentiation-of-x-sqrtx-how)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=x^{\log x}=e^{(\log x)^2}$. By the chain rule, the derivative is

$$f^\prime(x)=\frac{2\log x}{x} e^{(\log x)^2}=\frac{2\log x}{x} x^{\log x}$$

Comment: I did exactly that but instead I used $e^{\log x \ln x}$. That is where I got stuck. Why is it ok to write $\ln x$ as $\log x$? Isn't $\ln x$ appropriate since we are raising to the power of $e$?

Comment: @1xQ $\ln x$ is a short hand for logarithm of $x$ to the base $e$. One often also simply writes $\log x$ instead. They are in this case synonyms.

Comment: Thanks. and its 1xQ not Learner. Learner made the edit. And upvoting needs 15 reps and I only have 13. Would have upvoted if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Put $y = n^{log n} $
$$\implies \log y = \log n \log n \implies \frac{y'}{y} = \frac{\log n}{n} + \frac{ \log n}{n} = \frac{2 \log n}{n}  $$

$$ y' = \frac{y 2 \log n}{n} \implies y' = \frac{2 n^{\log n} \log n}{n} $$